# Proving a general statement about sequences and continous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, metric-spaces, proof-writing

It is fairly common in a first course on Analysis to prove that if $\{a_i\}$, $\{b_i\}$ are infinite sequences $ℕ→ℝ$ that converge to the points $a, b \in ℝ$ respectively then the sequence $\{a_i+b_i\}$ converges to the point $a+b \in ℝ$. The same idea works with subtraction, multiplication, division under non-zero elements, etc.

I believe that there might be a theorem that can work as a tool to prove all the previous statements in a general manner. If I'm correct, it would go something like this:

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space,

let $\{f_1, \ldots, f_n\}$ be a set of convergent sequences $ℕ→X$ such that $f_i(j)\in Y \subseteq X$ for all $i \le n, j \ge N \in ℕ$ and  $\lim \limits_{x \to ∞}f_i(x)=F_i \in Y$,

and let $g:X^n→X^m$ be a function continuous on $Y^n$.

Then $$\lim \limits_{x_1 \to ∞ , \ldots, x_n \to ∞}g(f_1(x_1), \ldots, f_n(x_n)) = g(F_1, \ldots, F_n)$$

---

However since I'm fairly new to Analysis I do not know how to prove such general claim, and I was wondering if anyone knew of a complete formal proof of it.

Any help/thoughts would be really appreciated.

Comment: Note my edits to the question for proper MathJax usage. In particular in expressions like $$ \{a_i, b_i\} $$ the $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ should be within MathJax. Also, if you use actual LaTeX, as opposed to MathJax, you will find that a,...,z and a,\ldots,z look different from each other, in that the latter is rendered as $a,\ldots,z$ and the former as $a,\text{...},z.$ $$ \begin{align} & a,\ldots,z \\ & a,\text{...},z \end{align} $$

Comment: @Arnaud Mortier. Would it be clearer if I change "convergent functions" by "convergent sequences"?

Comment: @Leo Yes, and also remove the "$(x)$" since $f_i$ is a function here while $f_i(x)$ is an evaluation of that function at input $x$. Note also that $x$ is perhaps not a very well chosen letter anyway for the argument of $f_i$ since $X$ is the codomain, not the domain, and since $x$ usually denotes a real number as opposed to $n,m,p,q,$ etc. which are all fine to denote a natural number.

Answer (score 1):

I will use the following two definitions.

> - If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, then $(X^n,d^n)$ is the metric space whose points are the cartesian product $X\times X\times \cdots \times X$, where $d^n((x_1,\dots,x_n),(y_1,\dots,y_n))=\max_i d(x_i,y_i)$.
> - Let $h:\mathbb N^m\to X$. We say $\lim_{x_1\to\infty,\dots,x_m\to\infty}h(x_1,\dots,x_m)=L$ if for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $N\in \mathbb N$ so $\min_i x_i\ge N$ implies $|h(x_1,\dots,x_n)-L|<\epsilon$.

$g$ being continuous at $(F_1,\dots,F_n)$ means that for all $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ so $$\max_i |y_i-F|<\delta \implies \max_j|g(y_1,\dots,y_n)_j-g(F_1,\dots,F_n)_j|<\epsilon.$$
So, given $\epsilon>0$, choose such a $\delta$, and then for each $1\le i \le n$, choose as index $N_i$ so that $$x\ge N_i \implies |f_i(x)-F_i|<\delta.$$

Letting $N=\max_i N_i$, then combining the last two paragraphs (with $y_i=f_i(x_i)$) shows
$$
\min_i x_i\ge N\implies |g(f_1(x_1),\dots,f_n(x_n))_j-g(F_1,\dots,F_n)_j|<\epsilon
$$
This is precisely the definition of $\lim_{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\to\infty} g(f_1(x_1),\dots,f_n(x_n))=g(F_1,\dots,F_n)$.